# Rails Tutorial sample_app fails in Heroku with log: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/about"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

I am following the online version of Rails Tutorial. The Sample_app in chapter 3 works fine locally, but when pushed to Heroku, the home page is found but not the other pages. Running heroku logs after trying to see the About page gives me (along with much else) the error above:

`2015-08-09T02:56:43.916991+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/about"):`

My routes.rb file is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'static_pages/help'
  get 'static_pages/about'
end
```

I have followed the directions carefully. I tried deleting and recreating the Heroku file. I did web searches and tried some things to no avail. My gemfile is straight from the online version of the book, which is using current versions.

---

**Solved:** #thedanotto had me run `heroku run rake routes` which showed that the help and about pages were directed to {root}/static_pages/about rather than {root}/about. I am still puzzled why the tutorial gives the about routes, which appear not to work as expected, and welcome any further comment, but I am marking this as solved.

Comment: What do you get when you run the command: heroku run rake routes

Comment: Great suggestion! I get
Running `rake routes` attached to terminal... up, run.3908
            Prefix Verb URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
              root GET  /                             static_pages#home
 static_pages_help GET  /static_pages/help(.:format)  static_pages#help
static_pages_about GET  /static_pages/about(.:format) static_pages#about
Sure enough, when I run https://enigmatic-beach-9653.herokuapp.com/static_pages/about the page shows up! I'll update my question below. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'll add a detailed answer that you can accept.

Comment: In order to mark a question as solved, please don't edit the question. Instead, please [mark an answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). That way, you and the accepted user get some reputation points and you help others find the correct answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I can't find a route, I run the terminal command

```
rake routes
```

Since you're on heroku you'll want to run

```
heroku run rake routes
```

Which will return something similar to the following.

```
Prefix Verb        URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
static_pages_about GET /static_pages/about(.:format) static_pages#about
```

So that shows that you can go to `www.[heroku_app_name].herokuapp.com/static_pages/about` And it will bring you to the page you want. You can also add a link to the page in a view by putting the following line of code within a view.

```
<%= link_to("About", static_pages_about_path) %>
```

That's all good stuff to know. But let's talk about using the controller action: `static_pages#about` with the path `/about`

Switch the following in `routes.rb` from

```
get 'static_pages/about'
```

to

```
get "static_pages/about", path:"/about"
```

or alternatively

```
get "/about", to: "rabbits#about"
```

You can read more about [Routes here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults)

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine locally, I assume you've set up the **controllers, views etc** properly.

Have you made sure to *commit all* those necessary changes *then* push?

e.g.

```
git add .
git commit -am "Added route"
git push heroku master
```

Comment: Great suggestion, but yes, I did those things. I've made progress--see my further comments.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the about page using the following URL ?
http://YourHerokuAppName.herokuapp.com/static_pages/about

[ Replace "YourHerokuAppName" with your Heroku App Name]

Comment: I am accessing the home page by https://enigmatic-beach-9653.herokuapp.com/ which works I access the about page by https://enigmatic-beach-9653.herokuapp.com/about which gives me the "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." message.

Comment: @WahhabB.. Exactly,  enigmatic-beach-9653.herokuapp.com/about is throwing you this error, because you have not defined any route for this in your route.rb file. If you want to access the about page using  enigmatic-beach-9653.herokuapp.com/about, then you can simply define a named route in route.rb file. Just replace:  get 'static_pages/about' by get 'about' =>  'static_pages#about'