# Heroku ActionController::Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Im getting a strange routing when on Heroku but not locally, and I have no idea how to proceed with it. this is the error:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/authors/posts/this-is-just-a-test/publish"):

Routes:

```
 new_author_session GET    /authors/sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
        author_session POST   /authors/sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#create
destroy_author_session DELETE /authors/sign_out(.:format)            devise/sessions#destroy
       author_password POST   /authors/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#create
   new_author_password GET    /authors/password/new(.:format)        devise/passwords#new
  edit_author_password GET    /authors/password/edit(.:format)       devise/passwords#edit
                       PATCH  /authors/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#update
                       PUT    /authors/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#update
                  root GET    /                                      blog/posts#index
           edit_author GET    /author/:id/edit(.:format)             author#edit
                author GET    /author/:id(.:format)                  author#show
                       PATCH  /author/:id(.:format)                  author#update
                       PUT    /author/:id(.:format)                  author#update
  publish_authors_post PUT    /authors/posts/:id/publish(.:format)   authors/posts#publish
unpublish_authors_post PUT    /authors/posts/:id/unpublish(.:format) authors/posts#unpublish
         authors_posts GET    /authors/posts(.:format)               authors/posts#index
                       POST   /authors/posts(.:format)               authors/posts#create
      new_authors_post GET    /authors/posts/new(.:format)           authors/posts#new
     edit_authors_post GET    /authors/posts/:id/edit(.:format)      authors/posts#edit
          authors_post GET    /authors/posts/:id(.:format)           authors/posts#show
                       PATCH  /authors/posts/:id(.:format)           authors/posts#update
                       PUT    /authors/posts/:id(.:format)           authors/posts#update
                       DELETE /authors/posts/:id(.:format)           authors/posts#destroy
                 about GET    /about(.:format)                       blog/pages#about
               contact GET    /contact(.:format)                     blog/pages#contact
                 write GET    /write(.:format)                       blog/pages#write
                 posts GET    /posts(.:format)                       blog/posts#index
                  post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                   blog/posts#show
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    extend FriendlyId 
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

    belongs_to :author

    scope :most_recent, -> {order(published_at: :desc)} 
    scope :published, -> {where(published: true)}

    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
        title_changed?
    end

    def published_date 
        "Published on #{created_at.strftime("%-b, %-d, %-Y")}"
    end

end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :authors
  root to: 'blog/posts#index'

  resources :author, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  namespace :authors do 
    resources :posts do 
      put 'publish' => 'posts#publish', on: :member
      put 'unpublish' => 'posts#unpublish', on: :member 
    end
  end


  scope module: 'blog' do
      get 'about' => 'pages#about', as: :about  
      get 'contact' => 'pages#contact', as: :contact
      get 'write' => 'pages#write', as: :write
      get 'posts' => 'posts#index', as: :posts
      get 'posts/:id' => 'posts#show', as: :post
  end
```

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912480/solved-rails-tutorial-sample-app-fails-in-heroku-with-log-actioncontrollerro) did not fix it.

Comment: For this route it is looking for id, but it looks likeyou are sending some type of slug, "publish_authors_post PUT    /authors/posts/:id/publish(.:format)", is there something with that route you are trying to do differently?  Something in the model to create a named route perhaps?  Model for post and route file would be useful to help

Comment: @RockwellRice added post and routes.

Answer (score 0):

However you are accessing `publish_authors_post_path` is sending a GET request when it's looking for a PUT request.

If you are using `link_to` you can use:

```
link_to 'Publish', publish_authors_post_path, method: :put
```

Or if you are using a form:

```
form_tag publish_authors_post_path(@post), method: :put
```

Comment: This is what I already had for that  `<%= link_to "Publish", publish_authors_post_path(post), method: :put, class: "btn btn-sm btn-success"  %>` but ist not working.

Comment: Do you have rails ujs enabled? @DavidK

Comment: its listed in my appilcation.js file, so yes?

Comment: Are you using `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`? Are there any errors in the javascript* console?

Comment: in application.html.erb i have a `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

Comment: Maybe try to use the data hash: `link_to 'Publish', publish_authors_post_path, data: { method: :put }`?

Comment: yeah nothing. no clue. Why wont it just work like it does locally?